# mod-wsgi with pylons on apache with preload?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, pylons

Is there a way to get this working with preload?  mod-php5 requires preload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean prefork?

mod-php5 requires apache2's mpm-prefork module.

mod-wsgi will work fine with prefork as well.